How do I convert an audio from byte[] to string?
I'm using Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) and when I try to make the program play a looping audio it says "Argument "1": cant convert from "byte[]" to "string"". The code is:
new Thread(() =>
{
     SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Anty);
     player.PlayLooping();

Anty is the name of the audio.
I tried converting the audio file from .wav to other formats but I'm pretty sure that the library only works with .wav.

SoundPlayer(string) expects a path string whereas your rescource is a binary audio file. Try reading a Resource Stream instead.

Remember that "Visual Studio" is just a code editor, just like Notepad. You can make your application in whatever editor you want - your question doesn't have anything to do with the editor you're using.

You can't pass a byte[] to any of the SoundPlayer constructors... and you don't want to convert this into a string, because the SoundPlayer(string) constructor accepts the path or URL to a wav file.
It sounds like you probably want to create a stream around the byte array, e.g.
new SoundPlayer(new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.Anty))

(Or any other way of getting a stream that reads from a resource.)
As a side issue, I strongly suspect you'll find that SoundPlayer shouldn't be constructed in a different thread to the UI thread.
